# Extended comments requiring two clicks again

Tags: bug, comments

On this question:

[SQL query filled Temdb complete Harddisk](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53584/sql-query-filled-temdb-complete-harddisk)

Click on the "add / show" link:

[image]

Initially you will see this:

[image]

Clicking the link again will reveal all of the comments. This is happening on other questions too (both on dba.SE and on SO) but this is one that is easy to reproduce (at least for me). Using Chrome 31.0.1650.57 on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Hm, not able to reproduce on Windows, Chrome 31.0.1650.57.

Comment: @acheong87 try refreshing the page a few times. It doesn't happen to me every single time. Perhaps it has something to do with the order things are loaded/rendered.

Comment: Is it possible that the scripts were still being downloaded when you clicked on the `add / show n more comments`?

Comment: Hm, hard-refreshed 10 times, still unable to reproduce. Do you have any extensions that disable Javascript or ads? (If so, does disabling them help?)

Comment: Can't reproduce on Mac OSX 10.8.5, Chrome 31.0.1650.57. It did take a bit for the comments to show though. Maybe you just need to wait a while?

Comment: Totally as an aside: I like the smaller `<code>` font on that site!

Comment: @Joshua ding ding ding - I waited 12 seconds and they finally appeared. Not the best UX ever. Maybe there should be some indicator that the site is trying - very slowly - to load 8 comments. Making me click repeatedly because I don't feel like anything is happening is just going to cause more load (and also it doesn't fully explain why my second click loads the comments immediately).

Comment: I'd be curious to see if the second click produces a second click creates a second network request, but I can't reproduce the delay.